# Java String to Python String Encoding "error"

Tags: java, android, python, string, encoding

Not sure if that is the best of titles but...

In my android app I'm trying to verify a signed string.

My method to do this works if I copy and paste the signedString and the Signature into my Django/Python method directly (I get these strings from my logcat).

But when I try to actually send that data to the server, it always comes up saying it is not verified.

I have tried .encode('ascii') and .encode('utf_8') [just blindly trying these things] and nothing has worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the encoding and decoding explicit on both ends just to make sure. So, in your Android app, first encode the String into UTF-8 bytes using [`getBytes("UTF-8")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29). Compute the signature of this byte array. Then, I'd encode the resulting byte arrays (the message and the signature) into [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29) to get nice chunk of ASCII with no whitespace that will survive any encoding on the wire.

On the Python side, do the reverse. [Base64-decode](http://base64.b64decode) the message and the signature. Compute the signature for the message string and compare with the received signature. (Remember than in Python before 3.x, a "string" is really a byte array, and a "unicode" is what would be considered a String in Java.) Then decode the message byte array using [`message.decode('utf-8')`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=decode#str.decode) to get what you started with on the Android side.

Comment: Didn't have to decode on the python side but everything works great! thanks : )

Comment: @IamAlexAlright The last decode isn't really necessary if you're not working with internationalised strings. In which case you could've used ASCII for the message <-> bytes encoding step, but with UTF-8 you can be sure it won't choke on any string.